# Delete CRLF in text file using Bash or Notepad++

Tags: bash, notepad++, text-files

I think this is easier than I think, anyway I would like to know your ideas.
I have this file:

```
AVP78031.1

AVP78042.1

ATO98108.1

ATO98120.1
```

But I need to do this:

```
AVP78031.1
AVP78042.1
ATO98108.1
ATO98120.1
```

Is there a way in NotePad++ to do this? However, I think this type of edition could do it in Bash Script or even only with the terminal. Is there a way to do this?

If you think that there is another way easier to do this, please let me know.

Any suggestion is always welcome.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: why not sed -i '/^$/d' myFile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using Notepad++

---

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(\R){2,}`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(\R)        # group 1, any kind of linebreak
{2,}        # may appear 2 or more times
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1, linebreak
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]